# Get part of string from notification data Android

Tags: android, json, push-notification

In my app, I get the data from a notification so I can use that in the app.
This is the way I'm doing it

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String jsonData = extras.getString( "com.parse.Data");
Log.d("Notification data", jsonData);
```

The log shows the following data

Notification data: {"alert":"lat/lng: (00.0000000,0.0000000)","push_hash":"SOME_VALUE"}

I want to get only the values from lat and long, in this example 00.0000000,0.0000000

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [json.org](http://www.json.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a third party library you can do

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
String alert = jsonObject.geString("alert");
```

Now you can get the lat/ lng using the java string method `substring(i,j)`.